# Angular Material input style and animation issue

Tags: angularjs, material-design, angular-material

Please checkout the images below.

This is showing the right animations and styles of input with red underlined border.
[image]

But most of the times this stying is not being rendered and also the placeholder does not hide when entering an input. To see the behavior check this image. 
[image]

you can see this live here at www.classroom.icoachu.us

The site is being developed in Angular material https://material.angularjs.org/latest/

I am unable to figure out the possible cause of this behavior.

Comment: Can you try not to combine so many frameworks together? Choose between Material Design Lite and AngularJS Material.

Answer (score 0):

It's not an angular issue. I get a 500 server error for `http://classroom.icoachu.us/favicon.ico`, so the side stops rendering and produces the second image.

Comment: I have applied the favicon.ico but it does not fix the issue. Can you confirm what can be the possible issue now?

Comment: Angular is not rendering the code if you change the site and go back, just when you refresh. I think you habe a wrong implementation with angular and material.